# Screen resolution only displaying 800x600 in Xubuntu

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, resolution, ubuntu-10.04, xubuntu

I am running Sun VirtualBox on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.

I have installed Xubuntu 10.4 as a virtual machine but cannot seem to find an easy way of altering the screen resolution. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a very thorough script to cover the issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725867/forcing-monitor-resolution-in-virtualbox-vm-on-linux-guest/10726041#10726041

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with VirtualBox.

You simply need to go to *Devices » Install Guest Additions* when you have Xubunutu running. This updates the OS.

Comment: Yes. You will have to install the guest additions once on every virtual machine, to enable full support for video and other drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with cvt and xrandr, short howto here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf

in the following section, add the three lines with similar values for your convenience:

```
"Monitor"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 70.0

    VertRefresh     50.0 - 160.0

    Option         "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
```

Be carefull with this values because they can destroy your monitor - have a look at the technical details for horizontal/vertical refresh rates.

Or connect your monitor with dvi-plug instead of vga.