# fullscreen VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screen resolution only displaying 800x600 in Xubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/139454/screen-resolution-only-displaying-800x600-in-xubuntu)

I recently created a virtual machine of Windows XP for a host computer running Mac OSX 10.6.8  However i find that the screen displayed by VirtualBox is far too small for any real work to be done. Where can i find the "Fullscreen" option? The option does not appear to be there under settings, and when i try stretching the window, it just creates a gray frame that is distracting and doesn't help anything.

Comment: Have you installed the VirtualBox Additions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the Virtualbox guest additions to do this. They are in the Devices menu, just hit that.

[image]

After that, they will appear in Windows XP's **My Computer.** You will see that there is a Virtualbox logo on the "Disk" it mounted. Inside there will be an executable for Windows. It may also auto-run.

[image]

Once thats done and you reboot the guest machine, you can go to **Machine > Full Screen**. It will also dynamically expand to whatever size you make the window, once the guest additions are installed.

Comment: It should be noted that once you verify that "VirtualBox Guest Additions (D:)" is in the "Devices With Removable Storage Section," you have to double click it to install.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the display resolution within the virtual XP. You may have to increase the virtual machine's video memory to be able to select a higher resolution. You can make VirtualBox fullscreen by doing [host key]-F (by default [host key] is the right CTRL key).

Comment: This will only work if drivers are installed, the virtualbox guest ones. If not, it will not function properly and will not expand, sticking to the `vesa` style drivers.