# virtualbox windows 7 gui stretched on mac

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screen resolution only displaying 800x600 in Xubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/139454/screen-resolution-only-displaying-800x600-in-xubuntu)
>   [fullscreen VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/399967/fullscreen-virtualbox)

When I try and open Windows 7 in VirtualBox on my Mac OSX 10.7.5, the GUI is stretched 100% wide and like 20px high. I can't do anything. Any ideas?

Running:
VirtualBox 4.2.6, 
Mac OSX 10.7.5
Windows 7

Comment: Have you installed the Guest Additions?

Comment: I think Guest Additions is installed. When I run in safe mode it works fine? I have no idea what is going on....

Comment: Safe Mode uses the base VGA driver that is deliberately made to be compatible with most adapters (and thus no fancy high resolutions or colour modes supported and so on). If you can, confirm that GA is installed or reinstall. This sure looks like a problem with the video drivers in the VM. See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/399967/fullscreen-virtualbox) for example.

Comment: Thanks heaps Karan. I try Devices > Install Guest Additions but get no response - no dialog box appears as per the screengrab from your link. I noticed I can choose Safe Mode with networking... I should be able to get buy on this for now I just need to run ie to test browser compatibility...